# SQL: how to select rows with values equal to thousand (1 column may contain several values)

Tags: sql, regex, t-sql

Would you help me, please, to select the rows which contain at least 1 value between 1000 and 1999.
The column I have (nvarchar(255):

col1

```
5501, 3500
3001, 3050, 4020
 1030, 1010, 1043, 2000
 3010, 1420, 8000, 2044
 1330, 1330, 8000, 3111
 1333, 1132, 8000, 1332
```

Desirable result:

```
1030, 1010, 1043, 2000
 3010, 1420, 8000, 2044
 1330, 1330, 8000, 3111
 1333, 1132, 8000, 1332
```

I've tried to use self written function splitstring:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_splitstring] ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

and `string_agg()`
but it works only with the single row.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1771/splitting-delimited-strings-using-xml-in-sql-server/

Comment: DaggeJ, thank you very much. I've got a lot from this artice. Along with the solutions from the article, post my variant (below)

Comment: Since you use the `regex` tag, looking for your number in beginning, middle or end of your fields should also work: `SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE col LIKE '1[0-9][0-9][0-9],%'
OR col LIKE '% 1[0-9][0-9][0-9],%'
OR col LIKE '% 1[0-9][0-9][0-9]';`. Edit: See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187489(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Answer (score 1):

For your particular problem, you can use `LIKE`.  Assuming all values are four characters (as in your example):

```
where codes like '%1[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Or:

```
where ' ' + codes like '% 1%'
```

Note:  Fix your data model!  Don't store numbers in strings!  Don't store multiple values as strings!

Comment: These would also match 10001, for example. See my comment on the question for how to narrow it down.

Comment: @oriberu . . . Read the first sentence of the answer.

Comment: Fair enough, though I would not immediately translate `For your particular problem` to `For this precise set of example data`. Shouldn't be quite that nitpicky, I suppose. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
    select * from table s
    where exists (select * from cmn.dbo.fn_splitstring(s.codes,', ') c 
where convert(int,c.item) between 1000 and 1999)
```

Where cmn.dbo.fn_splitstring is described above.